# VBA - add argument in countif

Tags: vba, countif

The code below aims to remove every row when the value in column M is 'Non Available' from sheet 'Summary' and put the entire row in another sheet 'Summarybis'. I'd like to add one argument in the countif function such as also removing every row with value in column M as 'To investigate'. How can I do except by creating a new code and replacing what I need?

```
Sub removing_rows()
Dim Check As Range, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("Summary").UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastrow2 = Worksheets("Summarybis").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If lastrow2 = 1 Then
lastrow2 = 0
Else
End If
Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M:M"), "Non Available") > 0
Set Check = Range("M2:M" & lastrow)
For Each Cell In Check
    If Cell = "Non Available" Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summarybis").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
        lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
        Else:
    End If
Next
Loop
End Sub
```

Finally, I think the above code is not entirely defined because it may happen that no output is produced (nothing is filled in sheet 'Summarybis'). What am I missing?

Thank you so much in advance ! :)

Comment: How about replacing `CountIf(Range("M:M"), "Non Available")` with `Countifs(Range(M:M),"Non Available",Range(M:M),"To investigate")`. It is also a good idea to qualify(define) all of the ranges with a worksheet like: `Worksheets("Summary").Range("M:M")`

Comment: thanks already! and what about the code line If Cell = "Non Available" Then ? Should I put If Cell = "Non Available" or "To investigate" Then ?

Comment: `If Cell = "Non Available" or Cell = "To investigate"` should work

Answer (score 2):

As @Victor K suggests try using countifs and don't forget to add condition to if regarding 'To investigate'

```
Sub removing_rows()
Dim Check As Range, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("Summary").UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastrow2 = Worksheets("Summarybis").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Do While ((Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M:M"), "Non Available") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M:M"), "To investigate")) > 0)
Set Check = Sheets("Summary").Range("M1:M" & lastrow)
For Each Cell In Check
Select Case True
    Case Cell = "Non Available"
    Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summarybis").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
    Case Cell = "To Investigate"
    Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summarybis").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
End Select
Next
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `COUNTIFS` will not work for two different criteria in the *same* column.

Comment: @Rory You are right. See the code: I think it is possible only `COUNTIF`

Comment: @Lincoln : why did you put the sign + between the 'Application.WorksheetFunctionCountif' in the Do  While ? And, should I also put the line  Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summar... just under the line Case Cell = "To Investigate" ? Thanks

Comment: @Jeofbist3 As it was mentioned by Rory it is not possible to countif same column by two criteria. Hence, use + to add two countif with two one criteria each

Comment: @Jeofbist3 also if you have lot of formulas in file don't forget to turn of [Calculations](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/applicationcalculation-xlcalculationautomatic/dad23ef7-dcaf-4eeb-8419-9d5427ea338f?auth=1) and [screen updating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-screenupdating-property-excel)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't very clear on one point : I also want to delete the rows with values 'To investigate' from sheet 'Summary' in column M and also put them in sheet 'Summarybis'.

I've tried the following (based on Lincoln's answer):

```
Sub removing_rows()
Dim Check As Range, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("Summary").UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastrow2 = Worksheets("Summarybis").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If lastrow2 = 1 Then
lastrow2 = 0
Else
End If
Do While ((Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M:M"), "Non Available") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M:M"), "To investigate")) > 0)
Set Check = Range("M2:M" & lastrow)
For Each Cell In Check
Select Case True
    Case Cell = "Non Available"
    Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summarybis").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
    Case Cell = "To Investigate"
    Cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summarybis").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
End Select
Next
Loop
End Sub
```

But Excel is freezing and no output is given.. Anyone has an idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

Please find corrected version of code, if you still need it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub removing_rows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim Check As Range, cell As Range
Dim rngS As Worksheet, rngSbis As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long, i As Long
Dim ro() As Integer, drow As Integer
Const key_word1 = "TO INVESTIGATE"
Const key_word2 = "NON AVAILABLE"

Set rngS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
Set rngSbis = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summarybis")

'Storing last rows to the varibles for future use
lastrow = rngS.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

ReDim Preserve ro(lastrow)
i = 0
'Copy of all rows that contains key words to the 'S' tab
Set Check = rngS.Range("M2:M" & lastrow)
For Each cell In Check
Select Case True
    Case UCase(cell.Value2) = key_word2
    cell.EntireRow.Copy
    rngSbis.Cells(rngSbis.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ro(i) = cell.Row
    i = i + 1
    Case UCase(cell.Value2) = key_word1
    cell.EntireRow.Copy
    rngSbis.Cells(rngSbis.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ro(i) = cell.Row
    i = i + 1
End Select
Next
'Deleting all rows with key words
For i = UBound(ro) To LBound(ro) Step -1
    On Error Resume Next
    rngS.Rows(ro(i)).Delete
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```